# How do I install m4a codec on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, m4a

I've seen a lot of answers to this question varying from release to release so I'm asking for my specific version 22.04 because neither vlc or audacity can open m4a files

```
VLC media player 3.0.16 Vetinari (revision 3.0.13-8-g41878ff4f2)
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f4cb8c75a00] moov atom not found
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55e4724c6c80] moov atom not found
```

Comment: Can you run the command `vlc /path/to/file.m4a` and post the output? You can [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1450401/edit) the question

Comment: Are you sure this is for all such files, or specific for *certain* files?  A quick google on that error indicates that the final part of encoding in those formats is generation of a moov atom, and that *not* being present means the recording of the files, etc. was prematurely terminated and therefore a required part of the video file is missing/gone/corrupt, meaning you have an incomplete or corrupt video file.  Do you have an example m4a file that is not copywritten or such that we can see as an example for others to test?